# How do I install a new system so it will ONLY start in safe graphics mode?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, graphics, mac

I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.4 on a late 2009 iMac in a dual boot configuration. To do this I have Ubuntu on a USB stick which is used to start up the iMac, so that it boots into Ubuntu and from there I install Ubuntu onto a drive partition. When I start up from the USB stick, I select the safe graphics option during boot up, otherwise the screen is a mess (the screen is divided into quadrants, each trying to replicate the Ubuntu screen, but they are all fuzzy and unreadable). Using the safe graphics option gives a perfectly good screen and all works well. However, when I then go to the next steps and install Ubuntu on the iMac's drive partition (to allow dual boot), after installation is complete and the system restarts from the drive partition, there is no option to select safe graphics, and I get the unusable quadrants screen, as shown here:

[image: Quadrant screen shown upon booting]

I've tried to interrupt the Ubuntu boot process using both Shift and Esc keys to try to get the startup options (as they appear when booting from the USB stick), but have no success - there are no such options when starting from the installed system. And when the system has started up, there is no way to read it in order to do something like run commands in the terminal (as suggested elsewhere when people were having startup problems or wanted to change their graphics drivers) since the display is so fuzzy and messed up. This is what the screen looks like when Ubuntu fully up and running:

[image: Ubuntu up and running - quadrants and not readable]

So my question is, is there a way to install the Ubuntu system (after startup from USB stick) with some option so that the newly installed system BY DEFAULT uses safe graphics mode? Meaning that changes are not made **after** the installation to fix this problem, but that the system defaults to safe graphics the first (and every) time it boots after installation. The default installer doesn't seem to have many options so I'm at a loss as to how to correct this.

One thing I've thought of which may be helpful is that I can access the newly installed system files from Ubuntu if I restart from the system on the USB stick. Perhaps it's possible to modify the installed system (on the drive partition) by use of the system booted up from the USB drive? But if so, I don't know what configuration changes to make or how to do that.

Many thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Your use of 20.04.2 media makes little sense to me; if you're wanting to use old media such as the capacity to use the GA kernel stack, using 20.04 or 20.04.1 media would make sense to me (ie. *different kernel drivers; which to the GA stack as you can have that installed from that media & no internet available to upgrade it during install*), or with HWE using the lastest/current ISO (20.04.4).. but why 20.04.2 using a EOL kernel stack (5.8) makes me wonder...   Post install aren't you getting to see the `grub` screen so you can enter `nomodeset` as a kernel option? (ie. use *safe graphics*)

Comment: @guiverc, I'm using 20.04.2 simply because it seem to be the default version available for desktops at https://ubuntu.com/#download. Sorry, I have no idea what you're referring to regarding the GA kernel stack - can you explain what that means in this context? No, as explained in my post I do not see the startup options (i.e. grub screen) and that's why I can't select the safe graphics option from the newly installed system.

Comment: I followed that link in your last comment, and I get offered [20.04.4](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/02/25/ubuntu-20-04-4-lts-released/) for download (not the older [20.04.2](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/02/05/ubuntu-20-04-2-lts-released/)...  Ubuntu LTS releases have two primary kernel stack choices (GA & HWE, and for some hardware other OEM option(s) may exist too!).  The significance of the kernel stack is *drivers* are actually kernel modules; thus a different kernel means different kernel modules (ie. *drivers*)  See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: The 20.04.2 ISO was the Ubuntu 20.04 LTS release with some security fixes PLUS the kernel stack from Ubuntu 20.10 (ie. GA or 5.4 kernel replaced by 5.8).  Ubuntu 20.04.3 included the kernel stack from 21.04 so 5.11 kernel, 20.04.4 includes the kernel stack from 21.10 so 5.13 kernel.. If using the HWE kernel stack the kernel will upgrade a few weeks before the next ISO release (dates in URLs in prior comment).. but systems using the GA (5.4 for 20.04) kernel stack do not change; it's the more stable option, esp. for servers or older hardware.

Comment: Not sure how I got 20.04.2, but in any case it makes no difference. I've now installed 20.04.4, with the same result as before. I've added some photos of the screens during and after booting to the original post. Again, holding Shift or Esc during startup makes no difference - can't get to any menu to select safe graphics.